# VueJS computed is returning false when the logic is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm stuck on a project vue2 with composition API, where my computed function is returning the wrong value.

```
<template>
<line-component v-if="displayLine"> </line-component>
</template>

<script>
setup(props){
    displayLine = computed(() => props.hasLine && props.id === props.selectedItems[0].id);
    return { displayLine }
}
</script>
```

Basically when I console.log the expression, i have true

```
console.log(props.hasLine && props.id === props.selectedItems[0].id)// true
```

but

```
console.log(displayLine.value);  // false
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: I see a missing parenthesis in your assignment

Comment: a mistake in my exemple

Comment: You have to `watch` the `displayLine` computed if you want to log changes. Check for typos too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the problem.
in the computed() I have a value that is not reactive: `props.selectedItems[0]`

This props value (an array) changes when there is a click event on the item but I was using to update the array.

```
handleClick = (id) => selectedItemd[0] = id;
```

I had to change it to

```
handleClick = (id) => selectedItem.slice(0, 1, id);
```

which is reactive now.